# Looking for replacement of "DIN" font

Tags: fonts

Initially I used "DIN" font for text. Later I come to know it is very rare and also need to install .That is not good idea for web page. Now I am looking something similar font and commonly available. also it should not required to install on the system.

Looking for suggestions.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not necessarily bound by common fonts that are likely to be installed on users' computers. CSS supports embedded fonts through the `@font-face` rule, though you should always check that the font you wish to embed allows you to do so in its licensing.

Comment: great suggestion, please let me know what is next step now

Comment: As I have said in my answer, the next step is to check whether the licensing terms of the "DIN" font allow embedding on web pages (and whether or not you have to pay for the font to do so), and if so, you can implement this with CSS. If not, you'll have to use a different font.

Comment: I would like to use different font. Good things are always free.. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You may find something similar in freely embeddable web font collections, for example here: http://www.google.com/webfonts

I don't know the DIN font, if it's [this one](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/fontfont/ff-din/), Dosis from the Google Webfonts collection has a somewhat similar feel.